# Adding a SCNBillboardConstraint makes the node disappear

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

After what I've read in the documentation and on the internet a `SCNBillboardConstraint` would rotate a node to always face the pointOfView node - in the case of `ARKit`, the user's camera.

The thing is, when I add a `SCNBillboardConstraint` to a child node, it disappears. The nodes are just some `SCNTexts` added as a subchild of a more complex model.
The hierarchy looks something like this: RootNode - > Text node (two of them).

Just after I added the root node to the scene's root node, I add this constraint in the following way:

```
updateQueue.async {
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(virtualObject)
    self.sceneView.addOrUpdateAnchor(for: virtualObject)
    self.addBillboardContraintsToText(object: virtualObject)
}

func addBillboardContraintsToText(object: VirtualObject) {
    guard let storeNode = object.childNodes.first else {
           return
   }

   for node in storeNode.childNodes {
        if let geometry = node.geometry, geometry.isKind(of: SCNText.self) {
            let billboard = SCNBillboardConstraint()
            node.constraints = [billboard]
        }
    }
}
```

The text nodes have their position set properly relative to their root node, so there's no problem with that. When I add a `SCNLookAtConstraint` though, it works just fine.

```
node.pivot = SCNMatrix4Rotate(node.pivot, Float.pi, 0, 1, 0)
let lookAt = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: sceneView.pointOfView)
lookAt.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
node.constraints = [lookAt]
```

Any ideas why the `SCNBillboardConstraint` might not work? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you looked as the .freeAxes parameter? e.g. billboard.freeAxes = SCNBillboardAxis.Y

Comment: Yes, it doens't have any effect. The labels still don't show up.

Comment: Same issue here SCNode with SCNText doesn't appear if I add `SCNBillboardConstraint`

Answer (score 0):

This Code (with apples CupScn) works just fine for me:

```
cupNode.position = SCNVector3(0.5,0,-0.5)
    guard let virtualObjectScene = SCNScene(named: "cup.scn", inDirectory: "Models.scnassets/cup") else {
        return
    }
    let wrapperNode = SCNNode()
    for child in virtualObjectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        child.geometry?.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
    }
    cupNode.addChildNode(wrapperNode)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cupNode)

    let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
    billboardConstraint.freeAxes = SCNBillboardAxis.Y
    cupNode.constraints = [billboardConstraint]
```